# How do you create a command that makes the bot go OFFLINE in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, command, bots

## Is it possible?

I want to create a command for my discord bot that makes the bot offline for everyone. I want to type that command in any discord server and then the bot just goes offline. This is much easier than going into your files or terminal to press ctrl+c. Is a command like this possible to even make? And if so, can I please know how to add that command? I want to add some admin commands to my bot and this is definitely a great addition to the list. Thanks -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest choosing a more graceful exit for your bot, which would be using `await bot.close()` if you are using master branch of discord.py, it cleanly closes the websocket connection it makes to discord.

```py
@bot.command()
async def shutdown(ctx):
   await ctx.send("Shutting down bot!")
   await bot.close()
```

If you are using the stable version, i.e 1.7.3 `which is installed when you do pip install discord.py`, you can use `await bot.logout()` instead

Unlike master branch's Bot.close, this drops all connections immediately.

```py
@bot.command()
async def shutdown(ctx):
   await ctx.send("Shutting down bot!")
   await bot.logout()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're trying to do here, you can just add a command that exits the `bot.py` program by making a call to something like `sys.exit()`. This would just terminate the program running the bot, making the bot go offline.